# How to access this array inner elements?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I'm trying to display category names of my categories table inside `select` HTML dropdown, but I'm getting

> Illegal string offset

Error all the time, no matter if I use `$value['category_name']` or `$key['category_name']`.

`Categories` table just have `category_id` and `category_name` columns with two rows.

How to access `category_id` in this array?

```
array(6) {
  ["Field"]=>
  string(11) "category_id"
  ["Type"]=>
  string(7) "int(11)"
  ["Null"]=>
  string(2) "NO"
  ["Key"]=>
  string(3) "PRI"
  ["Default"]=>
  NULL
  ["Extra"]=>
  string(14) "auto_increment"
}
```

My Code right now:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT categories.category_name FROM products LEFT JOIN categories ON (products.category_id = categories.category_id)";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `categories`";
$columns = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

$arr = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($columns, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}

<fieldset>
        <legend>Add Product</legend>
        <p>Product name: <input name="product" type="text" size="60" maxlength="100" required></p>
        <p>Category: <select name="category_id"><?php $i = 1;foreach ($arr as $entry)
                if($i > 1) {continue;}
                { ?><option value="<?php echo $entry['Field'];?>"><?php foreach($entry as $key=>$value) {var_dump($arr);} ?></option> <?php $i++; }?></select></p>
        <p>Price: <input name="price"></p>
        <p>Amount: <input name="amount"></p>
        <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add This Product"></p>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: There is nothing being rendered as HTML in your code

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton `<?php foreach($entry as $key=>$value) {var_dump($arr);} ?>` I left code like this for now, but echoing every array variation didn't help

Comment: What is the point in "select column"?

Comment: @u_mulder To output category names from categories table in DB. So that when user adds new product to DB,  he can choose category name from dropdown.

Comment: "Select columns" selects columns definitions for table, not values.

Comment: @u_mulder How do I modify my loop to select values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual code part of the PHP seems to be of the form:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT c.category_name 
        FROM products p
        LEFT
        JOIN categories c
          ON c.category_id = p.category_id";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

// the code below ignores result of the preceding query

$sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `categories`";
$columns = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

$arr = [];
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($columns, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
   $arr[] = $row;
}

$i = 1;
foreach( $arr as $entry ) if( $i > 1 ) { continue; }

// the preceding foreach loop is ended, so the following is not part of that loop
{
  echo $entry['Field'];
  foreach( $entry as $key=>$value ) {
    var_dump($arr);
  }
  $i++;
}
```

(There's no reference to `$result`, the result set from that first query just gets discarded. It's hard to determine what it is this is supposed to be accomplished. why is the variable `$i` even needed?  What is the deal with looping through every element of the array, and doing a "continue" on a condition that won't ever be satisfied? And why do we need to do a SHOW COLUMNS query?

It's just an incoherent rigmarole.

I'm just guessing, but it seems like the job we want to accomplish is retrieve a list of `category_id` and `category_name` values, and decorate that list as

```
 <select ... > 
   <option value="42">Computers     </option>
   <option value="43">Smartphpones  </option>
 </select>
```

But again, I'm just guessing.

It seems like we could retrieve that with a query, and store that in an array:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.category_id
             , c.category_name
          FROM products p
          LEFT
          JOIN categories c
            ON c.category_id = p.category_id
         GROUP
            BY c.category_id
             , c.category_name
         ORDER
            BY c.category_name";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
$arr = [];
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
   $arr[] = $row;
}
```

And once we have that done in the initialization, as then as we crank out the html page, when we get to the point we want to dump the list into the html, we would do that in a loop something like this:

```
  foreach( $arr as $val ) {
      echo $val['category_id'];
      echo $val['category_name'];
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, I totally didn't see that I was using wrong SQL query. It was supposed to be `$q` not `$sql` SHOW TABLES nonsense. No wonder I was not getting values. And yes you are right about what I want to achieve. Now my select dropdown displays category values. The `select` `value` attribute is supposed to have `category_id` which in my DB table 2 is equal to Computers category and 3 to Smartphones. Unfortunately the var_dump doesn't display category_id anywhere.

Comment: The query needs to return the `category_id` column along with `category_name` column, as shown in the example SQL I gave.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I get correct category id's now for my select attribute values and the name values in the dropdown. It's just that now when I have everything together and working, my dropdown list outputs both, the id number and name value in html in select like so: `2Smartphones` lol.
EDIT: Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

#### You have some errors in code.

Your foreach loop in your HTML code has the bracket in the wrong place:

```
<p>Category: <select name="category_id">
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($arr as $entry) { //<-- You was missing this
        if($i > 1) continue;
?>
```

Since your foreach loop is only populating a single value on each iteration, there would be no key.

```
<option value="<?php echo $entry; ?>">
```

Completed code:

```
$q = "SELECT DISTINCT categories.category_name FROM products LEFT JOIN categories ON (products.category_id = categories.category_id)";

$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `categories`";
$columns = mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);

$arr = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($columns, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>Add Product</legend>
    <p>Product name: <input name="product" type="text" size="60" maxlength="100" required></p>
    <p>Category: 
        <select name="category_id">    
            <?php 
                foreach ($arr as $entry) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $entry['category_name']. '"></option>
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Price: <input name="price"></p>
    <p>Amount: <input name="amount"></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Add This Product"></p>
</fieldset>
```

Sources: [PHP-foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Do you understand that each element of $arr is array?

Comment: @u_mulder what do you mean?

Comment: $entry is __array__, isn't it?

Comment: Okay, seems like you don't know what happens when  you echo array.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't fix anything.

Comment: @u_mulder I did change it. I forgot $entry was an array so I added the key.

Comment: You do the same error as OP - your query selects __definitions of columns__ and not columns values.

Comment: @u_mulder another under sight on my part. Do you agree that it's fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

For getting arrays content from your sql result just use below syntax

So instead

```
<option value="<?php echo $entry['Field'];?>">
```

please use

```
<option value="<?php echo $entry['category_id'];?>">
```

and instead

```
<?php foreach($entry as $key=>$value) {var_dump($arr);} ?>
```

use

```
<?php echo $entry['category_name'] ?>
```